# Arduino & NodeMCU, one server and multiple clients

Tags: wifi, nodemcu

I have seen another similar question and I followed the answer, but I cannot get my code to work for a single client properly.

In short, one NodeMCU provides AP and a WiFi server to multiple clients. The clients are supposed to stay connected. I am testing just a single client and it succeeds to connect and server reads just the first message, whereas all the subsequent messages are not received.

The server code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 10

IPAddress    apIP(42, 42, 42, 42);
const char *ssid = "ESP8266";
const char *password = "ESP8266Test";
WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient *clients[MAX_CLIENTS] = { NULL };

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  server.begin();
}

void loop () {
  WiFiClient newClient = server.available();
  if (newClient) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // Find the first unused space
    for (int i=0 ; i<MAX_CLIENTS ; ++i) {
      if (NULL == clients[i]) {
        clients[i] = new WiFiClient(newClient);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Check whether each client has some data
    for (int i=0 ; i<MAX_CLIENTS ; ++i) {
      if (NULL != clients[i]) //ako ima taj client {
        if (clients[i]->available()) {
          Serial.print("client "); Serial.print(i);
          Serial.println("data received");
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
          String request = clients[i]->readStringUntil('\r');
          Serial.println(request);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As one can see, I'm checking incoming connections with `server.available()`, whereas I check if there is some data over the existing connection with `clients[i]->available`.

What happens is that I get only the first message from the client. The client code follows:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "ESP8266";
char pass[] = "ESP8266Test";
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("W");
    delay(500);
  }
  client.connect(WiFi.gatewayIP(), 80); // Connection to the server
}

void loop () {
  client.println("0.00"");
  Serial.println("0.00"");
  delay(3000);
}
```

I suspect that I do not understand well the Server and Client classes from ESP8266WiFi Library, but it seems poorly documented.

Please advise.

Comment: i would just use the http examples if you only need 1/3Hz updates.

Comment: I believe it should work this way somehow, as http is more complex, and introduces unnecessary data and processing overhead. Maybe the problem is because the server node is also an AP?

Comment: I tried the both server and client nodeMCU's to be stations on another router's wireless network. Surprisingly, it works now.
Is this an issue with the library? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are not flushing the first data that's why only the first time your communication is happening but not after the subsequent time